# Validate OAuth/AAD token in SignalR

Tags: c#, oauth, signalr, jwt, adal

I have a signalR server and I need to validate an OAuth Token that the client will get from Azure AD. I want to do it in the AuthorizeHubConnection method.
I tried this http://geekswithblogs.net/shaunxu/archive/2014/05/27.aspx which basically does this:
var d

```
dataProtectionProvider = new DpapiDataProtectionProvider();
var secureDataFormat = new TicketDataFormat(dataProtectionProvider.Create());
// authenticate by using bearer token in query string
var token = request.QueryString.Get(WebApiConfig.AuthenticationType);
var ticket = secureDataFormat.Unprotect(token);
```

This will always return null in the ticket.

After a bit of searching I came across this article: http://ronaldwildenberg.com/signalr-hub-authentication-with-adal-js-part-2/

Here is what it does:

```
public class JwtTokenAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute  
{
  // Location of the federation metadata document for our tenant.
  private const string SecurityTokenServiceAddressFormat =
      "https://login.windows.net/{0}/federationmetadata/2007-06/federationmetadata.xml";

  private static readonly string Tenant = "yourtenant.onmicrosoft.com";
  private static readonly string ClientId = "12345678-ABCD-EFAB-1234-ABCDEF123456";

  private static readonly string MetadataEndpoint = string.Format(
      CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, SecurityTokenServiceAddressFormat, Tenant);

  private static readonly IIssuerSecurityTokenProvider CachingSecurityTokenProvider =
      new WsFedCachingSecurityTokenProvider(
          metadataEndpoint: MetadataEndpoint,
          backchannelCertificateValidator: null,
          backchannelTimeout: TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1),
          backchannelHttpHandler: null);

  public override bool AuthorizeHubConnection(
      HubDescriptor hubDescriptor, IRequest request)
  {
    // Extract JWT token from query string (which we already did).
    ...  

    // Validate JWT token.
    var tokenValidationParameters =
        new TokenValidationParameters { ValidAudience = ClientId };
    var jwtFormat =
        new JwtFormat(tokenValidationParameters, CachingSecurityTokenProvider);
    var authenticationTicket = jwtFormat.Unprotect(userJwtToken);

    ...
```

The problem with this is that it proposes to copy classes from the Katana project: https://katanaproject.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/Microsoft.Owin.Security.ActiveDirectory/WsFedCachingSecurityTokenProvider.cs.
This looks super ugly. Another problem is that I don't know the tenant id and I couldn't find it anywhere with the token. So even if this works, I would be one step away.

To wrap it up: I want to find a way to validate the AzureAD token with SignalR. It looked like a simple thing in the beginning. Is there a simpe way for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was simple:

```
JwtSecurityTokenHandler tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
tokenHandler.ValidateToken(token, authTokenValidationParameters, out validatedToken);
```